# How to Create an Object with Builder for a protobuf-net generated class in C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am currently trying to convert the following project(s) into C#.NET for my personal use. Both projects are similar with the major difference being the programming language. While converting I am facing an issue trying to construct an object for the protobuf-net generated class in C#.

The following are the original proto files which are used to generate the classes in all the projects :

https://github.com/Akdeniz/google-play-crawler/tree/master/src/main/protobuf

The generated class "BulkDetailsRequest" is instantiated in the following areas :

**Java based implementation**

Instance Creation : https://github.com/onyxbits/Raccoon/blob/master/src/main/java/com/akdeniz/googleplaycrawler/GooglePlayAPI.java (line 288)

Class Definition  : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/onyxbits/Raccoon/master/src/main/java/com/akdeniz/googleplaycrawler/GooglePlay.java (line 51237)

**Python based implementation :**

Instance Creation : https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api/blob/master/googleplay.py (line 208)

Class Definition  : https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api/blob/master/googleplay_pb2.py (line 3066)

For my C# based implementation, I had generated the C# classes using the https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/ using version "protobuf-net r668".

But there is no way to create an "usable" instance of the class either directly or using builder. For the class instance to be useable, the "docid" property of the class must be settable. Could this be an issue with protobuf-net generator or am I using it incorrectly ?

```
[global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"BulkDetailsRequest")]
  public partial class BulkDetailsRequest : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
  {
    public BulkDetailsRequest() {}

    private readonly global::System.Collections.Generic.List<string> _docid = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, Name=@"docid", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    public global::System.Collections.Generic.List<string> docid
    {
      get { return _docid; }
    }

    private bool _includeChildDocs = default(bool);
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = false, Name=@"includeChildDocs", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(default(bool))]
    public bool includeChildDocs
    {
      get { return _includeChildDocs; }
      set { _includeChildDocs = value; }
    }
    private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension extensionObject;
    global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
      { return global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing); }
  }
```

Comment: Because it's a repeated field, you simply use the list i.e. `bulkDetailsRequest.docid.Add("your-doc-id");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That member is a list. Just use `.Add(...)`, `.Clear()`, etc and the list indexers, i.e. `list[index] = value;`

For example:

```
obj.docid.Add("abc");
obj.docid.Add("def");
```